# I dont know why it does not print 2 and 3

Tags: python

I am asking to create a method that called `primes(x)`, which returns back a list that contains all prime numbers starting from 2 all the way to x.

Here is my code:

```
def primes(x):
    i = 2
    while(i < x):
        j = 2
        while(j <= (i/j)):
            if not(i%j): 
                break
            j = j + 1
            if (j > i/j): 
                print(i, " is prime")
        i = i + 1
```

It is expected to print:

```
>>> primes(50)
(2, ' is prime')
(3, ' is prime')
(5, ' is prime')
(7, ' is prime')
(11, ' is prime')
(13, ' is prime')
(17, ' is prime')
(19, ' is prime')
(23, ' is prime')
(29, ' is prime')
(31, ' is prime')
(37, ' is prime')
(41, ' is prime')
(43, ' is prime')
(47, ' is prime')
```

However, it did not print 2 and 3, it only printed:

```
(5, ' is prime')
(7, ' is prime')
(11, ' is prime')
(13, ' is prime')
(17, ' is prime')
(19, ' is prime')
(23, ' is prime')
(29, ' is prime')
(31, ' is prime')
(37, ' is prime')
(41, ' is prime')
(43, ' is prime')
(47, ' is prime')
```

Comment: Not your problem, but a general comment: you don't need the parens (`(` and `)`) in Python when using `if` or `while` statements. `if j > i/j:` and `while i < x:` will work just as well ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is this line:

```
while(j <= (i/j)):
```

When i is 2 or 3, the starting value of `j = 2` is causing the condition to evaluate to false the very first time.

Answer (score 0):

In the `while(j <= (i/j))`, when `i` is 2 or 3, the while loop doesn't activate.

Answer (score 0):

Ttake a look at

```
i = 2
while(i < x):
    j = 2
    while(j <= (i/j)):
```

Since `j = 2` is larger than `i/j`, i is only incremented and not printed. The same for `i = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is to print 2 and 3, then so it the easy way out ;)

```
def primes(x):
    i = 2
    print(2, " is prime")
    print(3, " is prime")

    while(i < x):
        j = 2

        while(j <= (i/j)):
            if not(i%j): 
                break
            j = j + 1
            if (j > i/j): 
                print(i, " is prime")
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: If `x` is less than 3, it will still print 2 and 3 for primes.